# Show only posts from todays date

Tags: loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
// End the loop.
endwhile;
else :
get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
?>
```

A simple loop her eon my index page.  I am using the No Future Posts plugin to publish posts with dates in the future but the most relevant ones are today.

I have been doing a ton of cutting and pasting code from around the net trying to find a way to get just todays posts to show but nothing is sticking.  I'm sure I need to check for todays date then put it into the loop but I have no idea how to do that, I know very little php, I usually just copy and paste other peoples code.

If any of the experts on here could maybe point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.!

Comment: I read through that and the people on there seem confused what theyre talking about so I have no chance

Comment: I am trying, I'm also starting from scratch.  Where do I put the code under the section labelled "Returns posts for today:" ?

Comment: Always file [edit]s to your question when try something (and fail). Describe what you tried and what _exactly_ failed. "Where do I put the code" probably is not the best question to ask on a _development_ site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want posts from today, it's super easy and right in the WP codex:

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; // end of custom loop ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```